# Histórico de navegação com history.pushState

Tags: javascript, ajax

Olá, pessoal. Seguinte, fiz um código para carregamento de conteúdo em Ajax e usei o history.pushState para mudar a URL do navegador, porém, quando clico em Voltar, não carrega o endereço anterior, apenas muda o link na barra de endereços.

Como faço pra quando clicar no botão Voltar, além de mudar a URL, carregá-la?

Agradeço a atenção!

Código JS:

```
function AbreEmDIV(endereco){
var linkMain = endereco.replace("ajax", "main")
var divConteudo  = "#conteudo"
var linkAtual = window.location.href
var obj = { Title: '', Url: linkMain };

$.ajax({url: endereco, success: function(result){
    $(divConteudo).html(result);
    window.history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
}});
}
```

Comment: Não funciona? `window.location = linkAtual;`ou `window.history.back(0);`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o evento [onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) para detectar quando o usuário clicar em voltar, por exemplo:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", event => {
    console.log( event )
    AbreEmDIV( event.state.Url );
});
```

Para isso é necessário alterar `var obj = { Title: '', Url: linkMain };` para

```
var obj = { Title: '', Url: linkAtual };
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi com:

```
$(window).on("popstate", function () {
    var linkAtual = window.location.href;
    AbreEmDIV(linkAtual);
});
```